# Select sub query if another sub-query returns true\false

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Like the title suggests, I am trying to achieve something like this

```
SELECT 

(<sub query>) AS some_result,

some_other_result = CASE WHEN some_result > 0 THEN (<another super heavy subquery>) ELSE NULL END

FROM some_table
```

and the output would be something like this

```
+-----------------------------------------+
+    some_result  +     some_other_result +
+-----------------------------------------+
+       0         +           NULL        +
+-----------------------------------------+
+       6.7       +       3.182738998     +
+-----------------------------------------+
```

I want to do this because `some_result` does not occur that often, but when it does it slows my query down.

I have a backup plan that uses 2 queries which will achieve the same thing, but I would like to avoid that approach if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Use a derived table (or cte).

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `some_result` in the upper level, not in the same where it was assigned. Something like:

```
select 
       a.*, 
       some_other_result = 
                             CASE WHEN a.some_result > 0 THEN (<another super heavy 
subquery>) 
                             ELSE NULL END 
from 
           (SELECT 
           (<sub query>) AS some_result
           FROM some_table) a
```

Comment: `FROM some_table`  should be removed.

Comment: @Serg I believe it was just a simplified example from author, if there are other fields in the same select excluding `sub_query`, `from some_table` might be needed

Comment: The question implies <sub query> returns a scalar value. Otherwise the original query would fail, but OP says it works.

Comment: @Serg I think you misunderstood me a bit, what I mean is that there might be other columns needed to be selected from `some_table`, along with `<sub_query> as some_result`.

Comment: OK, probably missing '*' in the inner SELECT is the reason.